# True or False (Big-O)

Tags: solution-verification, asymptotics, computer-science

I have the following question: $3^n = 2^{O(n)}$, is this true?

My explanation is that it is! My reasoning is that if we look at the exponents we see $n \le c\cdot n$ by definition of big-$O$.

But when I looked how it was solved, the author said: $3^n = 2^{O(n)}$ is valid because of $3^n = 2^{n\log3}$, so $n\log 3 = O(n)$.

Is my reasoning correct? Also, where did the author get the $n \log3$?

Comment: As far as I can tell, your reasoning is "look at the exponents, it's obvious!", which a) isn't awfully rigorous, and b) ignores the fact that $3 > 2$. I claim that it's not as obvious as you seem to think. Can you flesh out your "by definition" bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$2^{\log_2(3)}=3$ by definition. Therefore $3^n=(2^{\log_2(3)})^n=2^{n\log_2(3)}$. However, many authors omit the base of a logarithm when it either doesn't matter or is obvious from context, which is why $\log_2(3)$ has been written as $\log 3$ here.

$n\log3\in O(n)$ because, by definition of $O$, it satisfies $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n\log3}{n}=\log3\lt\infty$. Much more intuitively and commonly, it is $O(n)$ because it is a constant multiple of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

$2^{O(n)}$ is the set of functions $\{2^{\phi}\colon \phi \in O(n)\}$. So your reasoning is correct because $n \in O(n)$.

On other hand $3^n = 2^{n\log_2 3}=2^{\log_2 3^n}$ is well known identity. Sometimes it's called the main property of $\log$ or its definition: $a^{\log_a b}=b$. So, author is also correct because $n\log 3 \in O(n)$: for any $C>\log 3$ we have $n\log 3 < C\cdot n$.